# Deserialize dynamic object name for newtonsoft property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

When I am sending request for a certain API, they return me a json which is awesome, but the problem is that depending on the parameters I provide, the object name is always different while the data structure remains the same. So I am trying to convert the json to a C# class using Newtonsoft library. The only way I've found to do this is by using JsonTextReader, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of achieving this, I looked up the documentation and couldn't find anything to help me in that regard. I also tried using JValue.Parse for dynamic object mapping, but since the property name is always different, it doesn't help me.
Here is a code sample to illustrate the problem:

```
{
"error": [],
  "result": {
    //This property name always changes
    "changingPropertyName": [
      [
        "456.69900",
        "0.03196000",
        1461780019.8014,
      ]]
    }

//C# mapping
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public object[] Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("changingPropertyName")]
    public object[][] changingPropertyName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with an attribute.  You'd have to write a custom converter or something of the like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to deal with a variable property name is to use a `Dictionary<string, T>` in place of a strongly typed class (where `T` is the type of the variable property you trying to capture).  For example:

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public object[] Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Dictionary<string, object[][]> Result { get; set; }
}
```

You can then get the first `KeyValuePair` from the dictionary and you will have both the name of the variable property and the value available from that.

```
string json = @"
{
  ""error"": [],
  ""result"": {
    ""changingPropertyName"": [
      [
        ""456.69900"",
        ""0.03196000"",
        1461780019.8014
      ]
    ]
  }
}";

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

KeyValuePair<string, object[][]> pair = data.Result.First();
Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ":");
object[][] outerArray = pair.Value;

foreach (var innerArray in outerArray)
{
    foreach (var item in innerArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rlNKgw

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize it to a c# dynamic using:

```
dynamic dynamicObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResultString);
```