# Deserialize Newtonsoft Json data with Dynamic property name - C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923920/deserialize-dynamic-object-name-for-newtonsoft-property), which is similar to my issue but unable to fix the issue completely since the data structure is different and I am not able to figure-out how to apply this solution to my example data given below:

[image: JSon response]

```
{
    "result": {
        "RITM2572913": {
            "number": "RITM2572913",
            "state": "1",
            "stage": "fulfillment",
            "Sys_ID": "220e89681b31b384e3a0a79b2d4bcbf3",
            "requested_for": "1d1673c4dbda5b0072a85099dc9619b0",
            "Contoso_requested_for": "requested_for:1d1673c4dbda5b0072a85099dc9619b0,var_name_arr:",
            "Contoso_sc_Purposeofthef5request": "Add",
            "Contoso_Sc_Contactinfo": "Contact ",
            "Contoso_sc_Appname": "Application ",
            "Contoso_sc_Description": "Description",
            "Contoso_special_instructions": "special_instructions:",
            "business_justification": "Justification ",
            "Contoso_business_justification": "busess_justification:Justification",
            "Contoso_catalog_item_footer": "owner_info:"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the response data like this and need to de-serialize it to fit in the object model given below:

[image: object Model]

```
public class RITMGETRequestResponse
{
    public RITMDetails result { get; set; }

    public class RITMDetails
    {
        public string business_justification { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string requested_for { get; set; }
        public string stage { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string Sys_ID { get; set; }
        public string var_name_arr { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_business_justification { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_catalog_item_footer { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_requested_for { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_sc_Appname { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_Sc_Contactinfo { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_sc_Description { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_sc_Purposeofthef5request { get; set; }
        public string Contoso_special_instructions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In this case RITM number is dynamic. I need to get the Sys_ID and other properties of this JSON. How do I de-serialize this JSON response to get these values?

Comment: Post code as text, not images. Images can't be copied or compiled. Post code that actually reproduces the problem, including the JSON text. Don't post links to questions that may or may *not* be related to your problem. JSON.NET doesn't require hard-coded property names to begin with.

Comment: The answer to the linked question shows that you can convert the *parent* property into a `Dictionary<string,Whatever>`. In this case, the parent property is `result` so the class's property should be `public Dictionary<string,RIMDetails> result {get;set;}`

Comment: I have updated the question as per your suggestions. I will try this and will let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

straightforward example:

used a JSONProperty attribute to map result values of a dynamic property name

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var deserialise = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RITMRequestResponse>("{\"result\": {\"123\" : { \"number\" : \"123\" }}}");

        Console.WriteLine(deserialise);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class RITMRequestResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    public Dictionary<string, RITMDetails> RITMDetails { get; set; }
}

public class RITMDetails
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me. I had to spend some time to figure-out how to read the values from results but finally it worked. Here is how to read the values: `Dictionary<string, RITMDetails>.ValueCollection kvp = (new Dictionary<string, RITMDetails>(rITMGETRequestResponse.RITMDetails)).Values;`

Comment: if this works for you.. please make this as the answer ty